# How to get list of all the Members with their MFA status in IAM using Google Cloud API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I was trying to get the list of members (**Google accounts which i use to sigin in google cloud console project / IAM user accounts**) with their MFA status via GCloud API, I am not able to find any API endpoint for that, any help here?
Basically i am planning to create a report for cloud console IAM users who dont have MFA configured.

**Note: All i found**

- listing all service accounts at https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/list
- listing all accounts from identity platform: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.accounts/batchGet
- listing all accounts from workspace: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list

Comment: What type of users - Google Accounts, Workspace, Identity Platform, etc? Each service has its own API.

Comment: @JohnHanley i have API for workspace and cloud identity platform. looking for Google Accounts which i use to sing in to google cloud console projects.

Comment: Google Accounts does not have an API for you to call.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct Google Cloud API endpoint available to check the Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) status of a user. MFA is typically managed at the Google Workspace level rather than through Google Cloud APIs.

Please use google cloud IAM admin sdk with nodejs that can address your  query as in the official google documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/manage-mfa-users#before_you_begin

Comment: Thank you. well i am not looking for identity platform MFA. indentity platform API already available at https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.accounts/batchGet

 I am looking for Google Accounts MFA status which i use to sing in to google cloud console projects.